NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match when running env.production in node
I am running a typescript node project with default environment variables .env which is running well, as the command is
ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only --exit-child src/app.ts

then I built a production environment env config file - env.production
running the production mode with the command as
 NODE_ENV=production ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only --exit-child src/app.ts

in the console output, it comes with the warming -
WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names.

and the environment variables imported is also not the variables in .env.production file but variables in the .env file.
have no clues how to deal with this issue

This needs more context. Nothing in Typescript out-of-the-box uses .env files. What part of your application generates that error? Also, perhaps your file should be named .env.production instead of env.production if you're using typical 12 factor app conventions
